# XAML MVVM Multibinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have an MVVM WPF application, that has 'user settings' injected into the view. These settings contain things like last used search terms, or column widths on datagrids etc. This works nicely and the ViewModel is unaware of these settings as they are View Specific and a ViewModel may be shared by multiple views.

These values are bound to in the Xaml of the View.

However, some of the settings have a level of interference with properties on the ViewModel.

An example:

ViewModel has a property of `public int MaxResults { get; set; }` that is used to limit the number of results a query brings back.

When the user changes this value from, say, 100 to 50, ideally we want this saved in the View's settings; thus enabling the next time the View is used the value 50 is used rather than 100.

*my first question:*

How can I bind both the View Settings, and the ViewModel property to the same element? I am thinking a multi value converter, but am unsure of whether there are funkier ways of performing this operation. I need both the bindings to be 2 way, but also not get into any horrible update loops.

*my second question:*

Sometimes I'll want the ViewModel to take precedence over values supplied by the View Settings. I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions as to allowing one bound value take precendence over another.

Any comments / answers / questions greatly appreciated.

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are free - if you have two questions you can open two questions at no cost.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point in having the ViewModel ignorant of these settings. I'd have your VM in control of these user preferences and have the view pick them up via binding.

This has the advantage of you having control of these prefs from your view model AND you can test that your user preferences are being loaded correctly in the VM via your unit tests.

Remember, your VM is a View on your Model so having your user preferences loaded via your VM makes perfect sense here and much less likely to have edge-cases like these.